# NSString showing Null

Tags: core-data, nsstring

I am trying to access a core data model stored in another view controller. Currently, I have a few strings that i combine into one and save to the clipboard. But, when I paste the text, it shows NULL on the places where the three imported core data entries are supposed to be. What have I done wrong? Here is some code:

```
NSString *namevalue;
NSString *versionvalue;
NSString *companyvalue;
namevalue = [self.device valueForKey:@"name"];
versionvalue = [self.device valueForKey:@"version"];
companyvalue = [self.device valueForKey:@"company"];

NSString *shareString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I have performed %@ minutes of %@ %@",namevalue, versionvalue, companyvalue];

UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard setString:shareString];
```

Comment: Have you verified that `shareString` contains the correct values?

Comment: @MartinR I believe so. How do I check that?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the debugger, or print the values with NSLog() ...

Comment: ... and [DON'T PANIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Panic_(The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)#Don.27t_Panic).

Comment: @MartinR Ok, I set a breakpoint, and it breaks as expected. In the debug area, it shows all 3 NSStrings as nil. What now?

Comment: Then `self.device` probably has no values set for these properties.

Comment: It's also possible that self.device could be nil.

Comment: @MartinR Could you please leave an answer as to how I should set values then?

Comment: You'd set values the same as setting an attribute value on any other object. Since you're looking up the values here, surely you're either setting them at some point or intending to do so?

Comment: @TomHarrington I know that I have data set in my core data model because I display the data in a UITableView. I am trying to have it so that when an entry is clicked, a view controller loads and copies that data as a string into the clipboard.

Comment: @PanicDev: Did you check if `self.device` is nil?